# Listen for virtual keyboard input language change event

Tags: android, input

Is there an event that is fired when user changes input language on his/her virtual keyboard?
I'm trying to change Edittextfield layoutDirection on the go, if user decides to change the keyboard language (from English to Hebrew for example).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way.

You have to made a custom keyboard to send custom event (Input Type) to your application.